# How to start json-server dynamically

Tags: node.js, json, express, json-server

I have been working on a Node JS project and a particular API stores the received request body to the DB. For testing, I am using json-server to read and write data from a JSON file.

Currently I am using the classic way to start the json-server

`json-server --watch ./datastore/cion-config-datastore.json --port 9000`

The restriction is that the API should write the request body to the json file only if a particular set of conditions are met. Hence, I do not want json-server to be running at the background all the time and want it to be invoked only when needed.

```
app.post('/someapi',(req,res)=>{

    var someValue = req.body

    if(condition) // check the condition
    {
         // then start the json-server to watch the JSON file
    }

})
```

If I use the classic way of starting the json-server, then it has to be manually started every time even if not required.

It would be appreciated if someone could suggest a solution to invoke json-server dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [module child_process](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const json_server = spawn('json-server',
    ['--watch', './datastore/cion-config-datastore.json', '--port', '9000']);
```

Consider changing the paths to absolute path.

Make sure not to start the json-server multiple times. When you are lucky it will refuse to be started multiple times because the port is already occupied by another instance.